# Is there any sample/example available to use Google People API for iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, google-people-api

I went through he documentation for Google People API.

https://developers.google.com/people/v1/getting-started

I couldn't find any help/sample to implement the same for iOS platform.
Is there any help available for iOS platform?

Comment: @VidyaMurthy He is asking for People not Places.

Comment: It looks like Google does not have People API client library for iOS. So you'd have to  implement the model yourself and follow their rest API guide to implement the network calls.

Comment: Thanks @AuRis. Agreed. Google doesn't have People API client library for iOS. Also Couldn't find the same on anywhere else. Seems like need to implement on our own.

Comment: @Niraj you get anything for login user details like phone numbers, etc?

Answer (score 7):

Yes there is a People API client library for iOS. To include it you specify

```
pod 'GoogleAPIClientForREST/PeopleService', '~> 1.3.4'
pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 4.1.2'
```

in the Cocoapods pod file.

No, I havn't found any documentation of the Google People API client library for iOS except the source libraries themselves at https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest

Use the Google Calendar API iOS Swift sample code as guidance, setting

```
private let scopes = [kGTLRAuthScopePeopleServiceContactsReadonly]
private let service = GTLRPeopleServiceService()
```

The following code reads the contacts list for the signed in user.

```
// MARK: - Get Google Contacts

@objc func fetchContacts() {
    let query = GTLRPeopleServiceQuery_PeopleConnectionsList.query(withResourceName: "people/me")
    query.personFields = "names,emailAddresses,photos"
    service2.executeQuery(
        query,
        delegate: self,
        didFinish: #selector(getCreatorFromTicket(ticket:finishedWithObject:error:)))
}

@objc func getCreatorFromTicket(
    ticket: GTLRServiceTicket,
    finishedWithObject response: GTLRPeopleService_ListConnectionsResponse,
    error: NSError?) {

    if let error = error {
        showAlert(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

    if let connections = response.connections, !connections.isEmpty {
        for connection in connections {
            if let names = connection.names, !names.isEmpty {
                for name in names {
                    if let _ = name.metadata?.primary {
                        print(name.displayName ?? "")
                    }
                }
            }
            if let emailAddresses = connection.emailAddresses, !emailAddresses.isEmpty {
                for email in emailAddresses {
                        if let _ = email.metadata?.primary {
                    print(email.value ?? "")
                    }
                }
            }
            if let photos = connection.photos, !photos.isEmpty {
                for photo in photos {
                    if let _ = photo.metadata?.primary {
                        print(photo.url ?? "")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ps To make the Google Calendar API iOS Swift sample build without errors, you probably need to add a bridging header file (File > New > File, choose header file) and add the following:

```
#import <GTMSessionFetcher/GTMSessionFetcher.h>
#import <GTMSessionFetcher/GTMSessionFetcherService.h>
```

Then in the target Build Settings under the Swift Compiler - General heading, in the ObjectiveC Bridging header row add

```
projectname/bridgingheaderfilename
```

You may also then have to clean the build folder (Product menu, hold down options key).

Comment: getting error :  Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.

Comment: @DhavalBhadania I added an accompanying auth answer to add to Hugo's answer

Answer (score 2):

Adding on to Hugo's answer in Swift 4.2 you need to authenticate with the `GIDSignInDelegate` if you use the `GoogleSignIn` cocoapod, once you conform to this protocol you can add the following to your class init() along with an optional String

```
private var accessToken: String?

//init
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "Your client id via https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/people.googleapis.com"
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    if let error = error {
        print("Google sign in error: \(String(describing: error.localizedDescription))")
        return
    }

    guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
    self.accessToken = authentication.accessToken
    self.fetchContacts()
}
```

Now `fetchContacts()` looks something like this:

```
func fetchContacts() {

    let query = GTLRPeopleServiceQuery_PeopleConnectionsList.query(withResourceName: "people/me")
    let formattedToken = String(format: "Bearer %@", self.accessToken!)
    let headers = ["Authorization": formattedToken, "3.0": "GData-Version"]
    query.additionalHTTPHeaders = headers
    query.personFields = "names,emailAddresses,photos"
    query.pageSize = 2000 //max 
    services.shouldFetchNextPages = true
    services.executeQuery(
        query,
        delegate: self,
        didFinish: #selector(getCreatorFromTicket(ticket:finishedWithObject:error:)))
}
```

In AppDelegate.swift you need to call this method as well so that at the end of the authentication the url is properly handled

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                             sourceApplication:options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                             annotation: [:])
}
```